# OpenShift: Use custom node version

Tags: node.js, git, version, openshift

I need to use node 0.10.32 for an application that I would like to host on OpenShift. I tried using [this](https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift) script but it does not work. My console output when doing a git push looks like this:

```
remote: Building NodeJS cartridge
remote: npm info it worked if it ends with ok
remote: npm info using npm@1.3.24
remote: npm info using node@v0.10.25
remote: npm info preinstall nodejs-Custom-Version-Sample@1.0.1
remote: npm info build /var/lib/openshift/541b38b35973cae7d900030e/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: npm info linkStuff nodejs-Custom-Version-Sample@1.0.1
remote: npm info install nodejs-Custom-Version-Sample@1.0.1
remote: npm info postinstall nodejs-Custom-Version-Sample@1.0.1
remote: npm info prepublish nodejs-Custom-Version-Sample@1.0.1
remote: npm info ok 
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 5b53fccc
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting MongoDB cartridge
remote: 
remote: - pre_start_nodejs: Adding Node.js version 0.10.29 binaries to path
remote: - PATH set to include custom node version (0.10.29) from
remote: /var/lib/openshift/541b38b35973cae7d900030e/app-root/data//node-v0.10.29-linux-x64/bin 
remote: PATH = /var/lib/openshift/541b38b35973cae7d900030e/app-root/data//node-v0.10.29-linux-x64/bin:/var/lib/openshift/541b38b35973cae7d900030e/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/.bin:/var/lib/openshift/541b38b35973cae7d900030e//.node_modules/.bin:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/mongodb24/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
remote: Starting NodeJS cartridge
```

Can anyone identify the problem or has another to solution to install node 10.32?

Thank you very much

Tony

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did you upload the git repo `nodejs-custom-version-openshift` and then edit the below file?

`.openshift/markers/NODEJS_VERSION` with the contents:

```
0.10.32
```

then `git push`